# Exit status of a command with local variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a command in a function whose output is placed in a local variable. I want to get the exit status of that command, but `$?` always returns 0. When I use a non-local variable I get the expected exit status.

Here's an example:

```
function my_fun() {
   local output=$(ls no_file_here_buddy)
   echo $?  # returns 0

   non_local_var=$(ls no_file_here_buddy)
   echo $? # returns 2
}
```

How do you get the exit status of a command whose output is stored in a local variable?

Comment: This is [SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When using `local`, the `$?` contains the exit code of `local`, not of your command. Just separate the declaration of the variable from the assignment:

```
local output
output=$(ls no_file_here_buddy)
echo $?
```