# Local variables in zsh functions and their return code

Tags: shell, zsh, function, fzf

Consider the following zsh function

```
function foobar() {
    local foo=$(fzf) && echo "$foo-bar"
}
```

if instead of selecting one of the results of the `fzf` command I exit `fzf` without selecting anything, the second command is executed anyway and I get

```
-bar
```

on stdout. If instead I assign the variable without the `local` attribute the second command is only executed if I select something from `fzf`, which is what I want.

Since assigning variables with the `local` attribute in functions is preferable to not doing that, how can I fix that behaviour?

Comment: The exit status of declaring a variable local is zero if the variable was successfully declared local. If you want to capture the exit status of the `fzf` call, first declare the variable local, and then do the assignment. I'm fairly certain there's a duplicate for this, at least with regards to `local` in e.g. `bash`, where it behaves the same.

Comment: This is the equivalent `bash` case: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553258/exit-status-of-a-command-with-local-variable  And again: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281739/how-to-make-local-capture-the-exit-code  And again: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343254/why-does-local-fn-mask-the-status-code

Comment: You should post this as the answer so that I can accept it.